# Autenticação Asp.Net MVC usando FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, forms-authentication

Estou implementando a autenticação na minha aplicação ASP.NET MVC. Estou utilizando o `FormsAuthentication` para esta autenticação de cada usuário e para cada usuário logado 5 *sessions* são atribuídas (Nome, CodSetor, PastaPadrao, Status e CodPerfil). A autenticação está funcionando, no entanto não estou muito seguro se esta seria a melhor forma de autenticação tendo em vista que a aplicação será disponibilizada para N usuários (podendo ter mais de 1000 logados simultaneamente) e se a mesma é a mais segura e ainda pelo fato de utilizar 5 sessões para cada usuário?

O link que utilizei para implementar esta forma de autenticação foi : http://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-autenticacao-basica/20255

Caso tenham alguma ideia melhor e mais segura, ficarei muito grato em receber novas sugestões.

Comment: Pessoal, após pesquisar outras fontes vi que o asp.net mvc fornece uma forma de autenticação eficiente e segura conhecida como IDENTITY. Agora estou batalhando para adicionar esta ferramenta em um projeto a parte do projeto principal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A autenticação está funcionando, no entanto não estou muito seguro se esta seria a melhor forma de autenticação tendo em vista que a aplicação será disponibilizada para N usuários (podendo ter mais de 1000 logados simultaneamente) e se a mesma é a mais segura e ainda pelo fato de utilizar 5 sessões para cada usuário?

Como você mesmo disse por comentário, existem formas mais modernas de arquitetura de autenticação e usuários, como o ASP.NET Identity. Em todo caso, você não está colocando informações consideradas "perigosas" na sua sessão, como senhas e parâmetros que possam expor um usuário, ainda que você use Cookies persistentes para cada usuário.

[O Forms Authentication possui um processo intrincado para guardar as informações persistidas](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs). O processo em si não apresenta vulnerabilidades, mas não existe nativamente uma forma de proteger seu sistema contra tipos de ataques mais sofisticados como, o [XSS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Para resolver, você teria que implementar também [um mecanismo *anti-forgery*](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/).